# unable to retrieve image from custom content type

Tags: drupal-7

I've just started learning how to use Drupal 7. I made a new content type that will be displayed as a feed in my front page. All the data I need are being fetched and displayed correctly except for the image, whose url is always missing the actual file. I have another feed in my front page that uses the default article content type and all the images display properly.

The code I used for both is essentially the same, the only difference being the content type being retrieved.

This set worked:

```
$query = db_select('node', 'n');
$query->fields('n', array('nid', 'title'))
->condition('n.type', 'article')
->leftJoin('field_data_body', 'u', 'u.entity_id = n.nid');
$query->addField('u', 'body_summary');
$query->orderBy("nid", "desc");
$query->range(0, 3);
$result = $query->execute();

while($row = $result->fetchAssoc()) {
   $nid = $row['nid'];
   $node = node_load($nid);
   echo theme('image_style', array('style_name' => 'home-article-summary', 'path' => ($node->field_image['und'][0]['uri'])));
}
```

This didn't:

```
$query = db_select('node', 'n');
$query->fields('n', array('nid', 'title'))
->condition('n.type', 'news') //the only difference between the two is this line
->leftJoin('field_data_body', 'u', 'u.entity_id = n.nid');
$query->addField('u', 'body_summary');
$query->orderBy("nid", "desc");
$query->range(0, 3);
$result = $query->execute();

while($row = $result->fetchAssoc()) {
   $nid = $row['nid'];
   $node = node_load($nid);
   echo theme('image_style', array('style_name' => 'home-article-summary', 'path' => ($node->field_image['und'][0]['uri'])));
}
```

I tried making the settings of the content type I created the same as the ones for article throught Structure->Content Types but nothing happened. What am I missing? Thank you.

edit:
Upon inspection, I couldn't find a resized version of the image I uploaded for my custom content type. I'm assuming this means no resizing ever actually happened hence why the script didn't return a file. I still don't get why that happened.

edit the second:
never mind. I found the problem. it's all working fine now. was just using the wrong variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a bit of friendly advice for a Drupal newcomer, consider using [Views](http://drupal.org/project/views) to display lists of content instead of writing heaps of custom database queries. That will save you lots of coding in the long run.

Another argument for Views is that it's going to be included in Drupal 8 core.